# AWS Redshift SQL - PIVOT Query (multiple counts on one line/row)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to generate a single record (per account) for multiple status counts in Amazon Redshift. Basically, I want a pivot table. But I don't like this approach and I don't know if something better exists.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Select g1.account,
       sum(case when g1.status = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as status_cnt_pass,
       sum(case when g1.status = 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_new,
       sum(case when g1.status = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_fail,
       sum(case when g1.status = 'TEST' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_test,
       sum(case when coalesce(TRIM(g1.status ), '') != '' and g1.status not in('PASS', 'NEW', 'FAIL','TEST') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_other,
       sum(case when coalesce(TRIM(g1.status ), '') = ''  then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_none
```

Output:

```
account cnt_new cnt_fail cnt_test cnt_other cnt_none
foo     41      3        16       2         0
bar     105     17       5        1         1
```

Is there a better way to get a count for **other** values without maintaining a list?

> not in('PASS', 'NEW', 'FAIL','TEST')

Also, I want to stop checking for other status values, if a previous condition was true or status = null (or white space).

I don't own this table and I cannot change how the data is populated.

Comment: you are using the correct approach if you need that format for your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way.  But you can simplify your syntax using `::`:

```
select g1.account,
       sum( (g1.status = 'PASS')::int ) as status_cnt_pass,
       sum( (g1.status = 'NEW')::int ) as cnt_new,
       sum( (g1.status = 'FAIL')::int ) as cnt_fail,
       sum( (g1.status = 'TEST')::int ) as cnt_test,
       sum( trim(g1.status) not in ('', 'PASS', 'NEW', 'FAIL', 'TEST')::int ) as cnt_other,
       sum( (coalesce(trim(g1.status ), '') = '')::int ) as cnt_none
```